# PowerBuilder Find function throws an error "expression is not valid"

Tags: sql-server-2008, find, powerbuilder

What is wrong with this code. I am checking whether there is an available record in the database before inserting a new serial number. When I enter any record whether available or not, it throws an error message:

> "Expression is not valid". (PowerBuilder Classic 12.5 and SQL Server
>   2008)

```
If This.GetColumnName() = "serial_No" Then
 long ll_serial
    ll_serial=dw_newrecord.find(data, 1, dw_newrecord.rowcount())
    if ll_serial>0 then
    messagebox("validation error", "The record already exists")
    return 1
end if
End If
```

Comment: What is the value of `data` when you call `.find`? It could be an invalid sql expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your `data` expression has a syntax error. It can be some misformed code -like missing quotes- or maybe that the column name is incorrect.

To help for tuning a filter or find expression, you can test it in the datawindow design screen via the Rows / filter menu.

A better solution for long-term coding design would be to integrate the [Datawindow Debug Machine](http://geni.embeddingperl.com/index.php?post/2011/06/06/My-Datawindow-DebugMachine) (made by a colleague of mine) to your project. It is a precious tool to prototype datawindow expressions for finding, filtering but also for dynamic objects creation / modification in a datawindow. And while correctly interfaced with a datawindow ancestor of your project, it can help with filters and find expression errors like here.

EDIT: As RealHowTo noticed, the tool has been updated. Here is the [current latest version](http://geni.embeddingperl.com/index.php?post/2012/01/23/My-Datawindow-DebugMachine-v2.4) (but there is no updated demo screencast though).

Comment: If this script is from a standard event like ItemChanged, and Data is a system-provided parameter, then it *looks* like what you want to code is Find ("serial_No=" + Data, 1, RowCount()) if the column is numeric, or Find ("serial_No='" + Data + "'", 1, RowCount()) is the column is string.

Comment: @Terry, the problem was with the find function, i changed it to your answer and it worked!, ll_record=ds.find ("Serial_No='" + Data + "'", 1, ds.RowCount())

Comment: Nice tool ! Link to the latest version : http://geni.embeddingperl.com/index.php?post/2012/01/23/My-Datawindow-DebugMachine-v2.4